Validation not working in Spring Boot with Thymeleaf — Errors not displayed when fields are empty
In a Spring application I am using Thymleaf as a template. Errors are not displayed on the page
<form method="post" th:action="@{/add-client}" th:object="${clientRequestDto}">
<div th:if="${param.success}">
   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         Client successfully added
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label">Код</label>
   <input  class="form-control"  th:field="*{codeClient}" placeholder="160103650">
  <span class="validationError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('codeClient')}"
th:errors="*{codeClient}">Name error</span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Название торговой точки</label>
    <input  class="form-control" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Ашан">
     <span class="validationError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
th:errors="*{name}">Name error</span>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success">
<input type="reset" name="clearFilter" value="Очистить" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>

In DTO I use @NotEmpty to check fields
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class ClientRequestDto {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Вводите код")
    private String codeClient; 
    @NotEmpty(message = "Вводите название")
    private String name; 
  }

In the controller I use BindingResult for the error
@Controller
public class ClientController {

 @GetMapping("/clients")
    public String showClients(Model model){
     model.addAttribute("clientRequestDto", new ClientRequestDto());
     return "client";
 }

 @PostMapping("/add-client")
    public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("clientRequestDto") @Valid ClientRequestDto clientRequestDto, BindingResult errors){
      
     if(errors.hasErrors()){
         return "client";
     }

     return "redirect:/clients?success";
 }

Pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>wms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wms</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.6.0.Beta1</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I tried using Errors instead of BindingResult but it didn't help
If the fields are empty, Errors must return at least 5 error messages. But it returns 0 errors

